# How to use String.substring if the index value is beyond Integer?

Tags: java, string, substring, long-integer

Normally, I use `String.sustring(int, int)` method to get some part of a text.
If the text is too big, so I cannot access some position using Integer type variable,
What is the way of take care of this?

For example:

I would like to use `String.substring(Long, Long)`

Comment: The two answers here seem correct, but I'm inherently suspicious of any code that wants strings that large. Consider whether using streams or files might allow for more efficient code. Remember, a modern low-end computer still only had about 4 GB - if you're taking half of that up with one variable, that's concerning.

Comment: @raptortech97 As an array of `char` objects, which are 2 bytes each, a `String` of length `Integer.MAX_VALUE` would actually consume 4 GB.

Comment: Is it April 1st already??

Answer (score 8):

A string cannot be longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE since a String is represented with an array of `char`, and a Java array length cannot exceed this value. Look into the `StringBuilder` class for longer Strings.

Comment: Even `StringBuilder` is limited to an `int`. Note that the `length` and `indexOf` methods all return `int`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#length()

Answer (score 0):

The size of int is upto 2147483647. The value of your starting and ending index will not go up than that specified index.